# Custom output of user input in java using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

is there any way to get custom output, of user input using scanner?

For Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose one of the fruits:\n"+
            "1)Mango\n"+
            "2)Apple\n"+
            "3)Melon\n"+
            "4)Papaya\n");
        String fruit = input.next();
        if (fruit.equals("1") || fruit.equals("Mango")) {

        }
    }
}
```

So when i execute it, this is output

```
Choose one of the fruits:
1)Mango
2)Apple
3)Melon
4)Papaya

1
```

and it exits...

what i want is

```
Choose one of the fruits:
1)Mango
2)Apple
3)Melon
4)Papaya

1)Mango Selected
```

On pressing 1 it should print Mango Selected... Well i could have added println for that but i also want to not show 1 or Mango (whatever user entered) instead i want to show my custom message..

How to do it?

Comment: there is nothing in your `if` body

Comment: Are you wanting it to happen on they key press `1` or is it all right if they push `1` then `enter` before it comes up? Because from your question it sounds like you want it to happen on the key press.

Comment: when i press 1 and press enter it should print Mango selected and remove '1' which was printed above...

Comment: The problem here is the `1` that's entered is printed to the console, so you won't be able to remove that.

Comment: I added another part to my answer that may or may not help you. The number that the user enters won't get printed in the console. Check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can add them to a map and then get them by the key

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    Map<Integer, String> selection = Maps.newHashMap();

    selection.put(1, "Mango");
    selection.put(2, "Apple");
    selection.put(3, "Melon");
    selection.put(4, "Papaya");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Choose one of the fruits:\n"+
     "1)Mango\n"+
     "2)Apple\n"+
     "3)Melon\n"+
     "4)Papaya\n");

    int fruit = input.nextInt();

     System.out.println("you selected " + selection.get(fruit));  
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to enter the selection through the console then you can use a Dialog box

```
   Map<Integer, String> selection = Maps.newHashMap();

    selection.put(1, "Mango");
    selection.put(2, "Apple");
    selection.put(3, "Melon");
    selection.put(4, "Papaya");

    System.out.println("Choose one of the fruits:\n"+
    "1)Mango\n"+
    "2)Apple\n"+
    "3)Melon\n"+
    "4)Papaya\n");

    int mySelection = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 
    your selection here"));

    System.out.println("you selected " + selection.get(mySelection));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd store your fruits in an array, and print the option based on the user's input from said array.

```
String[] list = new String[]{"Mango", "Apple", "Melon", "Papaya"};
```

Print them first to the console:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

Then get and simply print the user's option:

```
System.out.println("Choose a fruit:");
int fruit = input.nextInt();
System.out.println(list[fruit - 1] + " selected.");
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/Uzj0Y1)